# Visual C++ generates DIV instead of IDIV (x86, integer arithmetic)

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++-2008, integer-division

I'm working with Visual C++ 2008 here (9.x) and I was preparing a fixed point value when I ran into the compiler generating a DIV instead of an IDIV. I collapsed the code into a tiny piece to exactly reproduce:

```
short a = -255;
short divisor16 = 640; // unsigned, 16-bit
unsigned int divisor32 = 640; // unsigned, 32-bit
unsigned short s_divisor16 = 640; // signed, 16-bit
int s_divisor32 = 640; // signed, 32-bit
int16_t test1 = (a<<8)/divisor16; // == -102, generates IDIV -> OK
int16_t test2 = (a<<8)/s_divisor16; // == -102, generates IDIV -> OK
int16_t test3 = (a<<8)/divisor32; // == bogus, generates DIV -> FAIL!
int16_t test4 = (a<<8)/s_divisor32; // == -102, generates IDIV -> OK

int bitte_ein_breakpoint=1;
```

I won't bother you with the simple disassembly.

Now instead of taking the shortcut and just changing the divisor's type (it is a function parameter, unsigned int numPixels), I wonder what makes the compiler pick DIV over IDIV in the third (test3) case, since it does not do so with an unsigned 16-bit divisor and there really isn't  anything that would call for unsigned arithmetic anyway. At least that's what I think and I hope I'm wrong :)

Comment: Shift, as said earlier, generates a SHL instruction which is logical instead of arithmetic. That seems wrong, but *256 does exactly the same in this piece.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code that is generated for the `/` operator depends on the operands.

First, the expression `(a << 8)` has type `int`, since *the integer promotions are performed on each of the operands* (ISO C99, 6.5.7p3), and then the operation is `int << int`, which results in an `int`.

Now there are four expressions:

1. `int / short`: the right hand side is promoted to `int`, therefore the `idiv` instruction.
2. `int / unsigned short`: the right hand side is promoted to `int`, therefore the `idiv` instruction.
3. `int / unsigned int`: the *left* hand side is promoted to `unsigned int`, therefore the `div` instruction.
4. `int / int`: nothing is promoted, therefore the `idiv` instruction is appropriate.

The *integer promotions* are defined in ISO C99 6.3.1.1p3:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions.*.

Answer (score 1):

Left-shifting a negative value results in undefined behaviour.  So I'm not sure you can draw many conclusions from what the compiler chooses to do in this scenario.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent by standard and it works in VS8. I did actually step through the asm and checked intermediate results.

Comment: I just checked ISO C99 6.5.7p4, and it clearly speaks of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I know and so does MS, that's why they speak of 'implementation-dependent'. VC does a SHL resulting in the desired *256 in this particular case, so it's besides the point.